# Display PHP variable values in separate HTML page

Tags: php, html, json

I am passing array from HTML page to PHP using xmlhttp. It all appears to be working fine. However, I need to verify that the PHP is receiving and decoding the JSON properly.

The code to read the JSON in PHP is as follows:

```
$str_json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$weekdates = json_decode($str_json, true);  

$MON = $weekdates[0];
$TUE = $weekdates[1];
$WED = $weekdates[2];
$THU = $weekdates[3];
$FRI = $weekdates[4];
```

A simple echo in PHP won't work because the PHP script is being called from the HTML page.

So how does one display the variable values from the PHP file to see if what is being sent is what is being received.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($str_json);` and `var_dump($weekdates);` ?

Comment: I would like to recommend using the developer tools of your browser and go to the _Network_ tab. There you will see what your page sent and what it received.

Comment: I assume  you are referring to F12 in IE. Correct?

Comment: How does one use F12 to examine PHP variables